# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tiles/web/startup/TilesListener while using Tiles in Struts 2

Tags: java, maven, struts2, tiles2, struts2-tiles-plugin

I'm integrated Tiles with Struts2 web application in Windows 8 OS. I am getting the following error in server log:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tiles/web/startup/TilesListener

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tiles.web.startup.TilesListener
```

I used the following necessary jars:

```
xwork-core-2.3.15.3.jar
struts2-core-2.3.15.3.jar
struts2-convention-plugin-2.3.15.3.jar
ognl-3.0.6.jar
javassist-3.11.0.GA.jar
freemarker-2.3.19.jar
commons-lang3-3.1.jar
commons-io-2.0.1.jar
commons-fileupload-1.3.jar
load-1.3.jar
asm-tree-3.3.jar
asm-commons-3.3.jar
asm-3.3.jar
tiles-api-2.0.6-sources.jar
tiles-compat-3.0.5.jar
tiles-core-2.0.6-sources.jar
tiles-jsp-3.0.5.jar
tiles-servlet-3.0.5.jar
tiles-portlet-2.1.4.jar
struts2-tiles-plugin-2.3.15.1..jar
```

My `web.xml` configuration:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
<filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/Login.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
 
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.DEFINITIONS_CONFIG</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>
<context-param>
    <param-name>tilesDefinitions</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
</web-app>
```

my `tiles.xml` configuration:

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 2.0//EN" "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_2_0.dtd">
<tiles-definitions>
<definition name="BaseLayout" template="/BaseLayout.jsp">
        <put-attribute name="title" value=" " />
        <put-attribute name="header" value="/Header.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="menu" value="/Menu.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="body" value=" " />
        <put-attribute name="footer" value="/Footer.jsp" />
</definition>

<definition name="/daywise.success.tiles" extends="BaseLayout">
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/BodyDayWiseSuccess.jsp" />
</definition>

<definition name="/daywise.tiles" extends="BaseLayout">
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/BodyDayWise.jsp" />
</definition>
</tiles-definitions>
```

what am I missing? I already spent a full day searching in google for a possible solution but not getting the right one.

Comment: i have edited the error please look up...

Comment: yes...its for the same question! but nobody answered that question :(

Comment: @narahare That question is off topic on SO and should be closed, below is the answer to your question, before asking the question you should know what are you asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a class. You are needed a class `org.apache.tiles.web.startup.TilesListener` but this file is found in the [tiles-core-2.0.6.jar](https://www.findjar.com/jar/org/apache/tiles/tiles-core/2.0.6/tiles-core-2.0.6.jar.html). This file you are missing.

If you don't want to download each file from the web, use Maven configuration in `pom.xml` like using the link below. Maven will download all required dependencies when you build the project using a [command](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#a-build-lifecycle-is-made-up-of-phases):

```
mvn package
```

Beside this a lot of errors are in the project files an configuration:

- mess up different versions of tiles
- using wrong and redundant context params
- mess up different versions of struts plugins
- missing more library dependencies
- using unused libraries
- using not supported servlet version

If you can't find links for Struts2 and Tiles2 integration you can read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15554374/573032) answer, it has a lot of links with code examples.

Comment: thank you for the reply...i tried adding tiles-cores-2.0.6.jar but still it is giving the following errors:

-> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tiles.TilesException
->java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/TimeSheetApp]]
->org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/TimeSheetApp]]

Comment: This is a topic to another question, read the rest of the answer and if you find it useful don't forget to upvote each answer and question that helped you in solving your problems.

Comment: the thing is i'm new and i dont know how to ask question and other things... and thank alot for the advice. i'll follow.

Comment: still getting the some more errors... for two different projects... i saw the example but same error came for that as well... can you please help me with this

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tiles/TilesException

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tiles.TilesException

java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[[/]]